# Is it possible to configure the Jackson XmlMapper to use single quotes instead of double quotes when serializing?

Tags: xml, jackson-dataformat-xml

Im trying to mimic the xml output by some really old C code which uses single quotes instead of double quotes for XML Attributes.  Jackson is currently outputting something like this:

`<test value="foobar"/>`

but I the existing C code would output:

`<test value='foobar'/>`

instead.  Is there a way to configure the XmlMapper to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up tracking down other similar questions from about a decade ago and found that its not possible to reconfigure STAX to do this because it would break the XML formatting.  I ended up extending XmlMapper as such:
`   public class XmlMapperQuotes extends XmlMapper {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
    @Override
    public String writeValueAsString(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return super.writeValueAsString(object).replace("=\"", "='").replace("\"/", "'/");
    }
}
```

`
Which will hopefully not break and blow up in my face.  I'm stuck dealing with a legacy XML parser written in C that cant be changed.